# Is there a way to see all the uv islands when uv sync is off?

Tags: uv, selection-tools

I'm trying to find out if there is a way to keep all the uv's visible without having to select the entire mesh with sync disabled.

The problem is that I want to be able to select a face or area in the viewport and see the corresponding face in the uv editor without the unselected areas disappearing.

I know I can use L hovering an area in the viewport to display the corresponding area in the uv editor, but that is not what I am looking for

Thx